# How to pass value from one Viewcontroller to another struct swift

Tags: swift

I'm doing pagination in TableView, for that, I need to pass a value from one ViewController to another struct

I'm creating a list of categories in tableview, So the id of each of this Category i need to pass to struct, So that Pagination is done correctly.

I get that id of a category, in a ViewController and that Id i need to pass.

For pagination using PagingDataController CocoaPods, previously I was able to pass an id directly(manually) for this CocoaPod, But for now, I'm dynamically passing id.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
var ida = id } 
}



struct Category: PagingProviderProtocol {
func loadData(parameters: AnyObject?, page: Int, completion: 
@escaping ([Dictionary<String, AnyObject>], Error?) -> Void) {
    var id = Cat_Id
    var cat1 = "category_id="
    var cat2 = cat1+id
     var cx = "https://stagecmsbmncapi.projectpresent.biz/client/article/" + cat2 + "&page=\(page+1)&per_page=\(pageSize)"

    Alamofire.request(cx, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
        var error: Error? = response.result.error
        var result: [[String: AnyObject]] = []
        print(response.result.value)
        defer {
            completion(result, error)
        }

        guard let data = (response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject]) else {
            return

        }
        result = data["result"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
    }
```

This var ida = id, I'm getting from previous TableView did select method. That id I need to pass to this loadData() inside struct to var id

This is the error message " Instance member 'ida' of type 'CatContentsVC' cannot be used on instance of nested type 'CatContentsVC.Category' "

Here CatContentsVC is ViewController having a TableView and Category is a struct as defined Below

This is the error message I'm getting, "Instance member 'of type ViewController cannot be used on instance of nested type ViewController"

Comment: I used User defaults and i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/call-struct-from-different-view-controller-swift4/35588/2), you need to add this to your code to make it work:

```
otherVC.referanceToOtherViewController = self
```